# How to post to Twitter and Facebook business page without notifications

Tags: facebook, twitter

I have a company website with a running blog. I created a business pages on Twitter and Facebook a while back but didn't had time to keep them up to date until I've finally created website. Now that I have website I have also 20+ blog posts I would like to post to Twitter and Facebook so that experience is similar (same information on website, Twitter, Facebook). I've plugins which will essentially publish the posts to Twitter and Facebook on demand. However I don't want to flood both Facebook/Twitter with posts

Is there a way to do this in a way so that people won't get notifications on Twitter and Facebook but if they would get into the page they would see those posts? I was thinking to disable Facebook page for a moment, post things, and re-enable. Not sure if it will work though? Is there some way to do this on Twitter? Preferably I would want to post those posts with "older" dates as well so that it's similar experience. What's the preferred way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually share one post per day or week for the next few weeks.

I don't think that there is any way you can manipulate the post-date on either Facebook or Twitter.     But there, it is not frowned upon to re-promote things that you originally shared on your blog some time ago.